# Issues with Image Cropping and AJAX Submission in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, iphone

I'm encountering some issues with my web project, particularly when using iOS Safari on certain iPhone models. The project involves cropping an image selected by the user, embedding it into a template, and then submitting it to a server via AJAX. Here are the problems I'm facing:

Problem 1: Image Cropping

Sometimes, after cropping the image using the Cropper.js library, the cropped image is not loaded onto the canvas. This issue appears inconsistently and is specific to iOS Safari.

Problem 2: AJAX Submission

After successful submission of the form, everything is saved on the server as expected. However, the AJAX error block is executed without any error response from the server. When I print the error, it's undefined. This issue also occurs sporadically on iOS Safari.